# Java - Multiple url-pattern and without extension

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My problem starts when I want to access to an url with this pattern ignoring any extension

`localhost:8084/project/foo/1`

I got this web.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Actually, to access to that url, I need to use `/foo/1.html` and I want to use `/foo/1`, because I will use that number as `id` to find an object and I don't know if I'm missing something, but this config doesnt work.

**Controller code**

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{id}")
    public ModelAndView telefono(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @PathVariable String id) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Code to search foo
        return new ModelAndView("foo", model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Check [this out](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html)

Try with this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
```

As /foo redirect to the servlet make /foo/1 will try to find /foo/foo/1

Comment: Yes, I've already tried. If I use that `url-pattern` it gives me a 404, even for `/foo/1` or `/foo/1.html`

Comment: Let me know the code for your controller or servlet, did you define @Controller(/{id}). It seems controller is not taking the request.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks ^^ Now, if I want to ignore `.html`, should I use a securityFilter? Its because it access with both urls `/foo/1` and `/foo/1.html`

Comment: Remove tag for <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>, as both url patterns are mapped to the same servlet

Comment: If I remove `*.html` I cant access to other urls that ends with that extension (`e.g: localhost:8084/project/info.html`). Any idea?

Comment: You should if resources are html pages and are outside of WEB-INF

Comment: Those resources are "semi-static" content and are `JSP` pages, so they are inside of WEB-INF

Comment: that is the problem without servlet .html you can not look within the WEB-INF, consider or moving jsp outside or a securityFilter to obtain access to them

Comment: I will use a security filter then :) Thank you so much for all the info.